# regex for parsing java enum

Tags: java, regex, enums

everyone!

I want to get enum constants using one regex

```
public*[ ]enum*[ ]DynamicVocabularyName[ ]*{([\ \n\r\t]*([A-Z\_]*)[ ]*\,)*[\ \n\r\t]*
```

input:

```
package ..;

public enum DynamicVocabularyName {
    ACTIVE_CRIMES_COUNT,
    ACTIVE_CRIME_TYPE,
    APPLICATION_NAME,
    ARREST_COUNT,
    AREA_DESCRIPTION,
    AREA_NAME,
    BAD_PARAMETER_NAME,
    BATTERY_PERCENT,
    CAROWNER_PERSON_ADDRESS,
    CAROWNER_PERSON_FULLNAME,
    CAROWNER_PERSON_PHONE,
    CRIME_DATE_DESCRIPTION,
    CRIME_SUBTYPE,
}
```

desired output - array of enum values:

```
ACTIVE_CRIMES_COUNT
ACTIVE_CRIME_TYPE
APPLICATION_NAME
ARREST_COUNT
AREA_DESCRIPTION
...
```

But I get only last enum value.

How to fix my regex to get all values?

Link to to this example:
https://regex101.com/r/rX7pJ1/3

Comment: What is your java code?

Comment: What if enum has fields i.e. `ACTIVE_CRIMES_COUNT("test")` ?

Comment: @D.Sergeev Did you mean to match `publi`, `publicc`, etc?

Comment: I use online service to write enums

Comment: I just want to get values of this simple enum, but my regex seems to return only 'CRIME_SUBTYPE'

Comment: Something wrong with `values()` and some `toString`/`name()`?

Comment: No they work fine, but for my task I must do it manually, parsing java file

Comment: Not to be rude, but *why* must you do this by hand?  Is this a homework assignment?  If not, this is a very strange requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not clear enough and you haven't provided some code, so if I understood your question correctly, then you can use a regex like this:

```
\b([A-Z_]+)\b
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/rX7pJ1/5)**

Answer (score 2):

- `public*` will match publi, public, publicccc, ...
  you should replace by (public)? => public zero or one time
- same for `enum*`
- `{` is special char in regex, so you need to escape it `\{`

With no guaranties, seems enough:

```
(\s*([A-Z][A-Z_]*)\s*[,\}]\s*)
```

Answer (score 1):

To capture all enum constants in your example code you can use this regex based on `\G` that asserts position at the end of the previous match.

```
(?:\spublic\s+enum\s+DynamicVocabularyName\s*\{|\G,)\s+([A-Z_]+)(?=[^{}]*\})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rX7pJ1/6)

Answer (score 1):

If you maybe have to deal with multiple different Java source files it might be worth to have a look at [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser).

For your current problem a solution might look like

```
// mvn artefact: com.google.code.javaparser:javaparser
//import japa.parser.JavaParser;
//import japa.parser.ParseException;
//import japa.parser.ast.CompilationUnit;
//import japa.parser.ast.body.EnumConstantDeclaration;
//import japa.parser.ast.body.EnumDeclaration;
//import japa.parser.ast.body.TypeDeclaration;

// mvn artefact: com.github.javaparser:javaparser-core
import com.github.javaparser.JavaParser;
import com.github.javaparser.ParseException;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.CompilationUnit;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.EnumConstantDeclaration;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.EnumDeclaration;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.TypeDeclaration;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class EnumNames {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
        String code = "public enum DynamicVocabularyName {\n"
                + "    ACTIVE_CRIMES_COUNT,\n"
                + "    ACTIVE_CRIME_TYPE,\n"
                + "    APPLICATION_NAME,\n"
                + "    ARREST_COUNT,\n"
                + "    AREA_DESCRIPTION,\n"
                + "    AREA_NAME,\n"
                + "    BAD_PARAMETER_NAME,\n"
                + "    BATTERY_PERCENT,\n"
                + "    CAROWNER_PERSON_ADDRESS,\n"
                + "    CAROWNER_PERSON_FULLNAME,\n"
                + "    CAROWNER_PERSON_PHONE,\n"
                + "    CRIME_DATE_DESCRIPTION,\n"
                + "    CRIME_SUBTYPE,\n"
                + "}";

        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(code.getBytes());
        CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
        List<TypeDeclaration> types = cu.getTypes();
        for (TypeDeclaration type : types) {
            if (type instanceof EnumDeclaration) {
                List<EnumConstantDeclaration> enumConstants = 
                        ((EnumDeclaration) type).getEntries();
                for (EnumConstantDeclaration enumConstant : enumConstants) {
                System.out.println("enum constant: " + enumConstant.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**output**

```
enum constant: ACTIVE_CRIMES_COUNT
enum constant: ACTIVE_CRIME_TYPE
enum constant: APPLICATION_NAME
enum constant: ARREST_COUNT
enum constant: AREA_DESCRIPTION
enum constant: AREA_NAME
enum constant: BAD_PARAMETER_NAME
enum constant: BATTERY_PERCENT
enum constant: CAROWNER_PERSON_ADDRESS
enum constant: CAROWNER_PERSON_FULLNAME
enum constant: CAROWNER_PERSON_PHONE
enum constant: CRIME_DATE_DESCRIPTION
enum constant: CRIME_SUBTYPE
```

Comment: The link to the project is the right one (it is pointing to the version on GitHub, the only one maintained) but the code refers to the old version. It is mostly the same code but you should change the package from japa.parser to com.github.javaparser

Comment: @FedericoTomassetti You are right. I didn't pay attention for that. I comment out the imports for the older version and add them for the recent one.